# Not able to run flutter app , error in app bundle gradle file

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to run the app, there is some error *'in app bundle gradle'* file. This error

```
Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml: /Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/FreeWheel_mobile_application/images/
```

Comment: Verify the entry of the image in pubspec is also present in asset folder

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access the image in the system URl,
edit your pubspec.yaml file saying `'\images'`.. i think you have put the images folder in the root directory.. so use that reference